# How to fix unexpected KeyError while mapping DataFrame column value to dictionary within loop in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, data-science, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to conduct a multivariate time series analysis using Facebook's Prophet library in Python. My goal is to predict the circumference of various muscles of an athlete over time.

My data consists of measurements of different muscles (such as 'Neck', 'Arm', 'Shoulder', 'Chest', etc.) along with their corresponding timestamps.

Firstly, I calculated correlations between different muscle measurements to use as regressors in the model. Here's an example of my code for this:

```
df_selected=df[[ 'Taille', 'Neck', 'Arm', 'Shoulder', 'Chest', 'Waist', 'Hips','Leg']]

# Calculate correlation matrix
correlation_matrix = df_selected.corr()

# Prepare a dictionary to store results
correlation_dict = {}
regressors={}
# For each target variable
for target in df_selected.columns:
    # Find variables that are strongly correlated with target
    strong_correlations = correlation_matrix[target].abs() > 0.40

    # Filter down to just these variables
    strong_correlators = strong_correlations[strong_correlations].index.tolist()

    # Remove the target from the list, as it's the variable of interest
    if target in strong_correlators:
        strong_correlators.remove(target)
    
        # Remove the target from the list, as it's the variable of interest
    if target in strong_correlators:
        strong_correlators.remove(target)

    # Add to dictionary only if there are strongly correlated variables
    if strong_correlators:
        regressor[target] = strong_correlators

# Print the correlation dictionary
for target, correlators in regressor.items():
    print(f"{target}: {correlators}")
```

Next, I created a function that takes a data group for a specific muscle and a dictionary of regressors. This function initializes a Prophet model, adds relevant regressors to the model, trains the model on the given data, and returns forecasted results:

```
def train_and_forecast(group, muscle, regressors):
    # Initiate the model
    m2 = Prophet()
    
    # Get the relevant regressors for the current muscle
    relevant_regressors = regressors.get(muscle, [])

    # Filter the group data to include only relevant columns
    necessary_columns = ['ds', 'y'] + relevant_regressors
    filtered_group = group[necessary_columns].copy()
    filtered_group['Muscle'] = muscle  # Add the 'Muscle' column back

    # Add each relevant regressor to the model
    for regressor in relevant_regressors:
        m2.add_regressor(regressor)

    # Fit the model
    m2.fit(filtered_group)
    
    # Make predictions
    future = m2.make_future_dataframe(periods=45)
    forecast = m2.predict(future)[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']]
    forecast['Muscle'] = muscle
    
    # Return the forecasted results
    return forecast[['ds', 'Muscle', 'yhat', 'yhat_upper', 'yhat_lower']]
```

Finally, I iterated over each muscle, retrieved the relevant data group, and called the forecasting function. The returned forecast is concatenated to a DataFrame which holds the forecasts for all muscles:

```py
necessary_columns = ['ds', 'Muscle', 'y'] + regressors[Muscle]
# Create an empty dataframe
for_loop_forecast = pd.DataFrame()
# Loop through each Muscle
for Muscle in Muscle_list:
  # Get the data for the mucle
  group = group[necessary_columns]
  # Make forecast
  forecast = train_and_forecast(group,regressor)
  # Add the forecast results to the dataframe
  for_loop_forecast = pd.concat((for_loop_forecast, forecast))

# Take a look at the data
for_loop_forecast.head()
```

And then it crash

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[259], line 1
----> 1 necessary_columns = ['ds', 'Muscle', 'y'] + regressors[Muscle]
      2 # Create an empty dataframe
      3 for_loop_forecast = pd.DataFrame()

KeyError: 'Neck'
```

However, I'm encountering a KeyError in the line where I try to determine the necessary_columns for the current group of data. The error message suggests that 'Neck' is not found in my regressors dictionary, although it should be.

I suspect that there might be a problem in the way I'm integrating these dynamic regressors with the Prophet model, or perhaps an issue with my data manipulation before the forecasting step.

How to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any code that adds to the `regressors` dictionary. Is `regressor[target]` a typo for `regressors[target]`?

Comment: "... 'Neck' is not found in my regressors dictionary, although it should be." <-This suggests that you haven't examined `regressors` to see if it contains the expected key. Have you tracked or checked the contents or `regressors` through the code to see where the dictionary diverges from what you expect to see?